# Forward Rstudio server port to multiple machines

Tags: r, rstudio, portforwarding, rstudio-server

I'm currently setting up an RStudio Server, but I needed to be quite safe. I had planned to set a tunnel for each user as we always do with other software, but RStudio Server cannot be launched multiple times with different ports.

Right now, we have it configured with:

```
www-address=127.0.0.1

www-port=8787
```

Is there any way to tunnel this 8787 port to multiple machines? Or is there any way to run rstudio server in multiple ports so that each user has one unique port for himself?

Comment: I don't think there's a way to launch multiple servers on multiple ports. The standard way of doing this is to create new linux users via `adduser`. They'll be able to log into RStudio Server and run their own R session.

Comment: I know, but the problem is that I don't want the server to be public, even though you have to log in to start working. That's why I wanted to multiple tunnels!

Comment: Then my bad. Actually I've found [this](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/219045167-Shiny-Server-Quick-Start-Run-Shiny-Server-on-multiple-ports) article that might point you in the right direction.

Comment: Unfortunately it's only for Shiny Server. I cannot use it with RStudio server, but thanks anyway!